# Spring valut config not loading

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

I have a project setup where I have a parent pom and child projects inheriting. We are using cloud config vault. It works fine as a separate project. I am able to store vault properties and load the same as given in the link here http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/

However, I need to use the vault in my child project that has a parent which is

using pom below -

Child pom`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

parent pom

```
<name>FEO Microservices Parent</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.M3</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>Finchley.M1</spring.cloud.version>
        <spring.cloud.stream.version>Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.cloud.stream.version>
        <springfox.swagger2.version>2.7.0</springfox.swagger2.version>
        <guava.version>20.0</guava.version>
```

`

here is the stack trace :

```
ramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultBootstrapConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0bf335]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1281) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1137) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:499) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:136) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:177) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:65) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:349) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.bbb.microservices.sku.SkuMicroserviceApplication.main(SkuMicroserviceApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0bf335]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:177) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:118) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:276) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultEndpoint.from(VaultEndpoint.java:85) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration.getVaultEndpoint(VaultBootstrapConfiguration.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration.<init>(VaultBootstrapConfiguration.java:109) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0bf335.<init>(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.0.M1.jar:2.0.0.M1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:165) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify you Vault properties, but judging by the error you are missing the `spring.cloud.vault.host` configuration.  Add the `spring.cloud.vault.host=<your_vault_host>` value to your properties and that should get you going.

Check [Spring Cloud Vault Quick Start Guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/) for more details.

Comment: those are available in the bootstrap.properties similar to how it worked for the demo project that i ran. #spring.application.name=demo
spring.application.name=${project.artifactId}
spring.cloud.vault.host=localhost
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.token=b7918e59-c701-2710-bf57-e388e3462dc0
spring.cloud.vault.uri=localhost:8200
spring.cloud.vault.connection-timeout=5000
spring.cloud.vault.read-timeout=15000

Comment: i suspect that there is some conflict with the maven dependencies as the parent pom is setup differently for project than the demo app i ran. It is   as follows:

Comment: <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>

Comment: <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>

Comment: <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
   <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
   <id>feo-repo</id>
   <name>FEO-Repository Replease</name>
   <url>http://11.185.55.148:8085/repository/maven-releases/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
   <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
   <id>feo-repo-snap</id>
   <name>SSS-Repository Snapshot</name>
   <url>http://11.185.55.148:8085/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </snapshotRepository>

Comment: </distributionManagement> <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.M3</spring.boot.version>
  <spring.cloud.version>Finchley.M1</spring.cloud.version>
  <spring.cloud.stream.version>Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.cloud.stream.version>

Answer (score 0):

I was earlier using uri without http:// just localhost:8200 this somehow worked in spring boot pre (2.0) version( I though gave other params too host name etc. in configuration). But, when i sort of moved the same code to Spring boot 2.0 that my project was using i ran in to the issue. Support team corrected this and i used http:// in uri and it worked  fine.